# Is Mutul authentication is a must for TLS?

Tags: security

I am working with RADIUS authentication using EAP-TLS. I used self signed CA and Server/Client certificate to establish mutual authentication.

that being said, is it absolutely necessary to have both server and client certificate to establish TLS ? If so then how does browser authenticates with only server certificate?
also EAP-PEAP (mschapv2) uses only server certificate to establish secure tunnel.

What are the handshake messages between server and client by which encryption key is derived.
thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EAP-TLS client identity is transmitted to the server by a client cert so it can authorize the certificate authenticated user.

Normally with EAP-PEAP client validates the server identity via TLS just like browsing to a secure site in your browser.

Server then validates client identity using inner user/pass authentication protocol (MSCHAPv2..etc) just like entering your username and password to login to the secure site you browsed to.

When doing PEAP + inner authentication client certificate validation is not necessary and normally not done.

EAP-PEAP derives network session encryption keys from the TLS sessions master just like EAP-TLS. The keys derived as a result of inner MSCHAPv2 authentication are not used for session encryption.

Comment: thank you for the reply I was able to understood the mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

It is the must for EAP-TLS and optional for PEAP. There is no browser in EAP-TLS. Do you mean 802.1x client?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply,
My bad, yes, I intent to mean 802.1x Client. How does browser derive the keystream from only server certificate.